# What is a counting number?

Tags: number-theory

The definition of **natural number** is given as **The counting numbers {1, 2, 3, ...}, are called natural numbers. They include all the counting numbers i.e. from 1 to infinity.** at the link http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_types_of_numbers.

What does counting number mean, are there any numbers which are not countable?

Comment: What do you mean by countable?

Comment: There is a possibility that two number can not be counted Ex:- infinity + infinity or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

Well, yes.  Consider 0, or -1, or $\frac{1}{2}$, or $\sqrt{2}$, or $\pi$, or...  None of these are natural numbers, but they are real numbers.

Comment: I am not able to understand how this post is answering what a counting number means ?. 1/2 + 1/2 = 1 countable right ?

Comment: The counting numbers are 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, and so forth.  Numbers like $1/2$ or zero are not counting numbers.  "Counting number" and "natural number" are synonyms.

Comment: its strange, infinity is considered as natural number but zero is not.

Comment: Infinity is not considered a natural number.

Comment: The definition at wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_types_of_numbers#cite_note-1 says natural numbers are 1 to inifinity

Comment: What the Wikipedia article is trying to say is that the natural numbers keep going, not that there's a natural number called infinity, though I do agree that it could be misleading the way it's written.

Answer (score 1):

The counting numbers are the positive integers. The positive numbers have always been considered suitable for counting. For example, a shepherd might have $47$ sheep; he probably would never say that he has $\frac{189}{4}$ sheep or $2 + \sqrt{-43}$ sheep (I can barely begin to imagine what such a complicated number means).

But what about $0$? Is that a counting number? Traditionally, no. In the earliest days of shepherding, $0$ was not even accepted as a valid number. Say our shepherd sold all his sheep. Then he would say he has no sheep, but he wouldn't say he has $0$ sheep. And if he had $47$ sheep, the idea that he could sell $50$ sheep would probably have been unthinkable.

Comment: Of course if he was a banker in shepherd's clothes, he'd sell you a thousand sheep.

Answer (score 0):

The counting numbers are $\mathbb{Z}^{+} =  \big\{1, 2,3....,∞\big\} $ also known as the natural numbers.

Even though the counting numbers go on on forever, they can be counted.

Given a set $X$,

$X$ is denumerable or enumerate if there is a bijection $\mathbb{Z}^{+} → X$.

A set is countable if either it is finite or it is denumerable.

Thus the set $\mathbb{Z}^{+} =  \big\{1, 2,3....,∞\big\} $, is countable since there is a bijection $\mathbb{Z}^{+} → \mathbb{Z}^{+}$.

This gives the listing $\mathbb{Z}^{+} =  \big\{1, 2,3....,∞\big\} $

The set of real  $\mathbb{R}$ numbers  is uncountable (not countable) since there is no bijection  such that  $\mathbb{R}^{} → \mathbb{Z}^{+}$.

For example, $∞$ cannot be map to 1, since infinity is not a number.

Thus there has to be a one to one and surjective relationship between the set of the natural numbers with the given set of numbers.

Comment: I don't think the OP was referring to countability in this sense

Answer (score 0):

Counting numbers are numbers you can use to count whole items. You can use the positive integers to count marbles, for example. Whether 0 is a counting number or not, that's a big debate you may or may not be interested in. As another answerer so amusingly noted, fractional and complex numbers are unsuitable for counting live animals.

As to whether numbers of a particular kind are themselves countable, that's a different issue that requires different words: you need to ask about count*able* numbers, not count*ing* numbers. For example, there are infinitely many rational numbers between 0 and 1 and you can count them in a *theoretical* sense even though you can't count them in a *practical* sense. I would start with $\frac{1}{2}$, continue with $\frac{1}{3}$, $\frac{2}{3}$, then $\frac{1}{4}$, $\frac{3}{4}$, $\frac{1}{5}$, $\frac{2}{5}$, etc. In short, I can give you a concrete algorithm that could theoretically count all these numbers.

There are also infinitely many irrational numbers between 0 and 1. I would start with $-1 + \sqrt{2}$. But what about $\pi - 3$? What about all those transcendental numbers we don't have symbols for? Even if I was a genius (which I am not), I couldn't give you an algorithm to count those numbers.